# Language switcher working only when Artisan serve is running

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I found an article about making a multilingual laravel website [here](https://mydnic.be/post/how-to-build-an-efficient-and-seo-friendly-multilingual-architecture-for-your-laravel-application), and it works like a charm.

But when I'm not running `php artisan serve` (on my hosting service for instance), switching languages redirects to 'original_language/lang/destination_language" and gives me a 404 RouteNotFound :

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179:
in RouteCollection.php line 179
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in LanguageController.php line 
22
at LanguageController->switchLang(object(Request), 'fr')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(LanguageController), 'switchLang'), 
array('request' => object(Request), 'lang' => 'fr')) in Controller.php 
line 55
at Controller->callAction('switchLang', array('request' => 
object(Request), 'lang' => 'fr')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), 
object(LanguageController), 'switchLang') in Route.php line 204
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 160
at Route->run() in Router.php line 559
```

I have absolutely no idea about where it's coming from. Here's my LanguageController.php method `switchLang()` :

```
public function switchLang(Request $request, $lang)
{
    // Store the URL on which the user was
    $previous_url = url()->previous();

    // Transform it into a correct request instance
    $previous_request = app('request')->create($previous_url);

    // Get Query Parameters if applicable
    $query = $previous_request->query();

    // In case the route name was translated
    $route_name = app('router')->getRoutes()->match($previous_request)->getName();

    // Store the segments of the last request as an array
    $segments = $previous_request->segments();

    // Check if the first segment matches a language code
    if (array_key_exists($lang, config('translatable.locales'))) {

        // If it was indeed a translated route name
        if ($route_name && Lang::has('routes.'.$route_name, $lang)) {

            // Translate the route name to get the correct URI in the required language, and redirect to that URL.
            if (count($query)) {
                return redirect()->to($lang . '/' .  trans('routes.' . $route_name, [], $lang) . '?' . http_build_query($query));
            }

            return redirect()->to($lang . '/' .  trans('routes.' . $route_name, [], $lang));
        }

        // Replace the first segment by the new language code
        $segments[0] = $lang;

        // Redirect to the required URL
        if (count($query)) {
            return redirect()->to(implode('/', $segments).'?'.http_build_query($query));
        }

        return redirect()->to(implode('/', $segments));
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Hope it's helping. Thank you !

(I can feel that's it's a root/public folder routing problem but I can't find where)

Answer (score -1):

This problem takes very long time from me to be solve.

You have two options:

1. Make separate domain on your OS and make sure removing public from path.
2. Upload your project in a real domain that's work with me.